# Alamofire convert bool on int

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have func for request and have dictionary for params. Dictionary contained [String, Any]. And i need send Bool in parameters but alamofire convert my Bool on Int and server can't get it. How i can send Bool?

my func:

```
func postDataFor(methodPath: String, params:[String:Any], completion: @escaping (Any)->()) {
    guard let url = URL(string:baseURL+methodPath) else {print("fail url"); return}

        let token_type = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token_type")
        let access_token = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "access_token")

        let headers:HTTPHeaders? = ["Authorization": "\(token_type ?? "") \(access_token ?? "")"]


        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: headers).response { response in

            if let data = response.data {
                completion(data)
            } else {
           print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

This i try send:

```
    ▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "promoId"
    - value : 6
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "isFavorite"
    - value : true
```

But this send alamofire:

```
?isFavorite=1&promoId=6
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess all these values are stored in `params`. If so, change `isFavorite` to a string:

```
let params = [
    "promoId": 6,
    "isFavorite": String(isFavorite)
]
```

Comment: This worked for me like a charm. Answer upvoted..!!

Answer (score 2):

Use for encoding parameter as:

```
// Define custom encoding with URLEncoding.BoolEncoding.literal
let encoding = URLEncoding(boolEncoding: .literal)
```

Example:

```swift
import Alamofire

func postDataFor(methodPath: String, params: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + methodPath) else {
        print("Failed to create URL")
        return
    }

    let tokenType = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token_type") ?? ""
    let accessToken = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "access_token") ?? ""

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "\(tokenType) \(accessToken)"]

    // Define custom encoding with URLEncoding.BoolEncoding.literal
    let encoding = URLEncoding(boolEncoding: .literal)

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: encoding, headers: headers).response { response in
        if let data = response.data {
            completion(data)
        } else {
            print("Error: No data received")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

With this modification, Bool values will be encoded as true or false literals instead of being converted to integers. Now, when you call postDataFor, your Bool parameters will be correctly encoded.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.